# Finding the intersection between two lines

Tags: c#, math, geometry, unity-game-engine

So I've been banging my head over this relatively simple algorithm. I'm not sure what's wrong in my code yet I'm not getting the intersection point where they are actually intersecting.

I'm using Unity3D and I'm trying to find the point where two lines intersect, in the x,z plane though not in the x, y plane. I am assuming that the algorithm which works for x,y should work for x,z;

My code:

```
Vector3 thisPoint1 = thisCar.position + (2 * thisCar.forward);
Vector3 thisPoint2 = thisCar.position + (20 * thisCar.forward);

Debug.DrawLine(thisPoint1, thisPoint2, Color.white, 2);

Vector3 otherPoint1 = threateningCar.position + (2 * threateningCar.forward);
Vector3 otherPoint2 = threateningCar.position + (20 * threateningCar.forward);

Debug.DrawLine(otherPoint1, otherPoint2, Color.white, 2);

float A1 = thisPoint2.z - thisPoint1.z;
float B1 = thisPoint1.x - thisPoint2.x;
float C1 = A1 * thisPoint1.x + B1 * thisPoint1.z;

float A2 = otherPoint2.z - otherPoint1.z;
float B2 = otherPoint1.x - otherPoint2.x;
float C2 = A2 * otherPoint1.z + B2 * otherPoint1.z;

float det = A1 * B2 - A2 * B1;

float x = (B2 * C1 - B1 * C2) / det;
float z = (A1 * C2 - A2 * C1) / det;

return new Vector3(x, this.transform.position.y, z);
```

Can anyone help into pointing out what I'm doing wrong?

`thisCar.forward` and `threateningCar.forward` are usually either `[0,0,1], [0,0,-1]` or `[1,0,0], [-1,0,0]`

Comment: Do you check if the lines are parallel, i.e. det == 0? According to the vectors you submitted, both cars are moving along the x or z axis. And since you are using float, you can divide by 0.

Comment: I'm not no, but in in most cases they're perpendicular if not exactly 90 degrees somewhere close definitely not parallel though

Comment: But in that case, shouldn't the vectors' combinations be [0,0,1], [-1,0,0] or [1,0,0], [0,0,-1] or similar?

Comment: Ah yes, I think I was misunderstood in the question. Those are all the possible values of the .forward vector (in my simulation). I am only performing this check when the cars are at an intersection so they are most likely at a 90 degree angle to each other. That is why I shouldn't have parallel lines

Comment: Well, the code looks OK, can't see any possible error.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756435/finding-the-intersection-of-two-lines)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it!!!

```
float A2 = otherPoint2.z - otherPoint1.z;
float B2 = otherPoint1.x - otherPoint2.x;
float C2 = A2 * otherPoint1.z + B2 * otherPoint1.z;
```

Should be:

```
float A2 = otherPoint2.z - otherPoint1.z;
float B2 = otherPoint1.x - otherPoint2.x;
```

`float C2 = A2 *  otherPoint1`**.x** `+ B2 * otherPoint1.z`;

Lot's of wasted time for nothing :/.

Anyways this will help anyone looking to do line intersection.

Answer (score 0):

you could parent an empty GameObject to the car and place it slightly in front of it (either in the IDE or on start). That way you can safely get the two points needed to draw a line.

Comment: Yep, I'll try that, although technically I can't see why mine isn't working. I have a feeling that your solution should do it. Will try it out later at home. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you knew the distance `t` this car needs to travel and `u` the other car, then the intersection point is trivial.

```
Vector3 intersection = thisCar.position + (t * thisCar.forward);
Vector3 intersection = threateningCar.position + (u * threateningCar.forward);
```

But you can solve for `t` and `u` using some algebra, and the 2D vector cross product, `[x_1,z_1] × [x_2,z_1] = (x_2 z_1 - z_2 x_1)` which is the `y` a scalar value of the 3D cross product.

```
t = Vector3.Cross(threateningCar.forward, thisCar.position - threateningCar.position).y 
    / Vector3.Cross(thisCar.forward, threateningCar.forward).y;

u = Vector3.Cross(thisCar.forward, thisCar.position - threateningCar.position).y 
    / Vector3.Cross(thisCar.forward, threateningCar.forward).y;
```