# Finding the intersection of two lines

Tags: ruby, intersection, algebra

I have two lines:

```
y = -1/3x + 4
y = 3x + 85
```

The intersection is at `[24.3, 12.1]`.

I have a set of coordinates prepared:

```
points = [[1, 3], [4, 8], [25, 10], ... ]
#y = -1/3x + b
m_regr = -1/3
b_regr = 4
m_perp = 3 #(1 / m_regr * -1)    

distances = []
points.each do |pair|
  x1 = pair.first
  y2 = pair.last
  x2 = ((b_perp - b_regr / (m_regr - m_perp))
  y2 = ((m_regr * b_perp) / (m_perp * b_regr))/(m_regr - m_perp)
  distance = Math.hypot((y2 - y1), (x2 - x1))
  distances << distance
end
```

Is there a gem or some better method for this?

NOTE: THE ABOVE METHOD DOES NOT WORK. See my answer for a solution that works.

Comment: @theTinMan I'm just not sure that deleting the entire application/purpose of the cude and description of what he's tried so far is an appropriate use of editing abilities

Comment: I believe it was unnecessary extraneous information, leading to a TL;DR. It's important to remember that Stack Overflow isn't a forum, and the goal is to create a Wikipedia-like repository of questions and answers. Encyclopedic articles aren't conversational and are factual. The gist of the question remains after the edit and is stated concisely now. You are welcome to flag it for a moderator if you disagree.

Comment: However, a sentence or so explaining **why** a question is being asked sets the context for some regulars. In nearly every other anthropological context this information, especially if explained in brief, is considered valuable information. That and I was cognizant of the fact that search engines might pick up some of the discussion about getting standard deviations from a trendline in ruby, which is virtually unmentioned on the internet.

Comment: Haha no this is an intellectual debate I'm also somewhat of a stackoverflow wizard myself

Comment: Then you are more than welcome to reestablish the context. That's the beauty of SO; It's community-run and community edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much suffering and many different tries, I found a simple algebraic method [here](http://math.ucsd.edu/~wgarner/math4c/derivations/distance/distptline.htm) that not only works but is dramatically simplified.

```
distance = ((y - mx - b).abs / Math.sqrt(m**2 + 1))
```

where x and y are the coordinates for the known point.

Comment: why can't you just define a function `def get_x_int(b2,b1,m1,m2); (b2-b1)/(m1-m2); end;` ?

Comment: I could, lambdas seem more compact though. They can be defined in the initialize section and stored in instance variables.

Comment: I guess you could; it depends on the larger context of your code but it's typically less idiomatic.  is this supposed to be a method of a class/instance?  it could just be a class method, or even an extension of the `Math` module.  it's "universal" and there's really no reason to create a new proc object every time when you can just call a class/module method, like you would `sqrt`.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with using a little math?

If you have:

```
y = m1 x + b1
y = m2 x + b2
```

It's a simple system of linear equations.

If you solve them, your intersection is:

```
x = (b2 - b1)/(m1 - m2)
y = (m1 b2 - m2 b1)/(m1 - m2)
```

Comment: It might not have been your math, I was debugging a lot of different variables, but at the time this didn't work

Comment: @boulder_ruby can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

For Future Googlers:

```
def solution k, l, m, n, p, q, r, s
  intrsc_x1 = m - k
  intrsc_y1 = n - l
  intrsc_x2 = r - p
  intrsc_y2 = s - q

  v1 = (-intrsc_y1 * (k - p) + intrsc_x1 * (l - q)) / (-intrsc_x2 * intrsc_y1 + intrsc_x1 * intrsc_y2);
  v2 = ( intrsc_x2 * (l - q) - intrsc_y2 * (k - p)) / (-intrsc_x2 * intrsc_y1 + intrsc_x1 * intrsc_y2);

  (v1 >= 0 && v1 <= 1 && v2 >= 0 && v2 <= 1) ? true : false
end
```

The simplest and cleanest way I've found on the internet.